# Unexpected token in JSON at position 0 --- 2 Different Webservices

Tags: javascript, json, titanium

Ok, i have this problem.
Im making an app from Appcelerator.

I started the testing in a cloud server.

The JSON returns this to me

```
[{"id":"100001","password":"0001","nombre":"Alejandro O","invitado":"12"}]
```

Later, i bought a server and installed Xampp for the mysql server and apache to get the JSON generated.
Everything set it up just fine.
And the server gaves me also a "JSON" format

```
[{"id":"400002","password":"123321","nombre":"GLORIA LETICIA LUQUE CASTELAZO ","invitado":"12"}]
```

The problem: The first server works fine with the result
The second one drops me an error

> Unexpected token ﻿ in JSON at position 0

Is the same format.
I tought "Ok, is dropping me as a string"

so i tried to JSON.stringify and all posibles ways to make that value to a string and then to parse it as a json object.

Im new on this, and i dont have any idea of what else to try.

Comment: Here is the answer i have given please check it https://stackoverflow.com/a/46398326/3900712