# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

With some help, I have managed to make a form that validates and confirms user password before adding the user to the database. I have encountered some problem as the data of the user is not sent and giving me the following error :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 0 
>  at JSON.parse () 
>  at Object.success (confirm3.php:29) 
>   at i (jquery.min.js:2)  
>  at at A (jquery.min.js:4) 
>  at
>   XMLHttpRequest. (jquery.min.js:4)

The error

> at Object.success (confirm3.php:29)

is referring to this following line

```
var data = JSON && JSON.parse(response) || $.parseJSON(response);
```

The POST variable

```
$UserNm=$_POST["UserNm"];
$UserId=$_POST["UserId"];
$UserPwd=$_POST["UserPwd"];
```

To make things clear, the data that should be returned is `$ReturnMessage` which is retrieved from stored procedure. `$ReturnMessage` will display the status of the operation for both successful and fail operation.

An example of `$ReturnMessage` :

> "USER ID EXIST. (011 CODE)." 
>   "USER ID MINT20 ADDED."

POST method is used : `if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {`

**$ReturnMessage :**

```
 if(isset($ReturnStatus) && $ReturnStatus==1) {
 $ReturnMessage=odbc_result($stmt,'ReturnMessage');
 }
 }

 $ReturnMessage = utf8_encode ($ReturnMessage);
 echo json_encode($ReturnMessage);
 }
```

**Script :**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("#myForm").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var password = $("#UserPwd").val();
    var confirmPassword = $("#ConfirmPassword").val();
    console.log(password,confirmPassword)  
    if ($.trim(password) === password && 
      password !== "" && 
      password === confirmPassword) { 
      $.ajax({
        url: "confirm3.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: { Submit: "true" },
        success: function(response) {
          var data = JSON && JSON.parse(response) || $.parseJSON(response);
          alert(data);
        }
        });
        } else {
          alert("Please Enter Password Correctly");
        }
      });
});
<script>
```

I'm kind of confuse. Please guide me. Thank you.

Comment: The `$ReturnMessage` example value that you show seems to be a string, not an object/array, so why are you calling `json_encode` on it? What happens if in your JS you delete the `var data = ...` line and just `alert(response)`?

Comment: you are returning a string

Comment: I did replace them. What happened is a popup with a html of some part of my form and some html of `xdebug-error` which include error of `undefined index` come out. @nnnnnn

Comment: @guradio What should I add to the code to accept the string?

Comment: This is not JSON format `"USER ID EXIST. (011 CODE)."` - this is: `{ "response":"USER ID EXIST. (011 CODE)."}` so `success: function(response) {
     alert(response) },` is currently a better idea

Comment: I'm kind of confuse as a popup which contains my code including the script and html keep coming out and not the `$ReturnMesage` @mplungjan

Comment: Then the php is not parsed by your server. Try call it from postman or temporarily change post to get and call it from the location bar

Comment: @mplungjan I think I just found the problem. The ajax script is not working even from the beginning. I misunderstand as the `$ReturnMessage` is echo through `echo json_encode($ReturnMessage);` and not in a popup. Also, the postman test on POST request fails.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set your content-type in your php?

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Also you don't need to put "true" in quote marks, when the json gets to your php script, once you run json_decode, php will recognise it as a boolean.

Comment: Is there a specific line to add the content-type? I deleted the quote mark and replace them with this `data: {Submit: true},` @Konda Thank you for telling me that.

Comment: The header is in the PHP

Comment: I include them under the `echo json_encode($ReturnMessage);` @mplungjan

Comment: You'll need to put the header line at the top before any php code runs. 

<?php 
header('Content-Type: application/json'); ...

Comment: The page now displayed all of my code instead of the form. Any idea? @Konda

Answer (score 1):

First of all, jQuery can decode JSON automatically for you (and it will make its best to guess). Trying to do it manually only makes your code more verbose and error-prone. However, you don't give it any hint. Nothing in the code you've shared gives any clue about your intention to use jQuery.

All the phases where you can do so, in chronological order:

1. Report data type from web server. If you happen to be using Apache:

   ```
   <Files "confirm3.php">
       ForceType application/json
   </Files>
   ```
2. Report data type from PHP:

   ```
   header('Content-Type: application/json');
   ```
3. Tell jQuery that you expect JSON:

   ```
   url: "confirm3.php",
   method: "POST",
   dataType: "json",
   data: { Submit: "true" },
   success: function(response) {
       console.log(data); // Already decoded (don't use alert to debug!)
   }
   ```

You can certainly omit almost any step, but not all.

Secondly, if you get a JSON parse error the very first you need to check is whether the response is valid JSON. The most straightforward way to see it is using the browser developer tools, more specifically [the "Network" pane](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor).

Answer (score 0):

Use this in my case there was some null bytes so this i figured out and it fixed my issues.

```
var data3 = data.substring(data.lastIndexOf("{")+1,data.lastIndexOf("}"));
      count = $.parseJSON("{"+data3+"}");
      alert( count.firstname ); // firstname is the key so you can use anything to test it.
```